# .NET MAUI Blazor: How to change MainPage to a custom razor page

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

How do I change the App.xaml MainPage to a custom razor page:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Best regards H

I have tried this: `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Pages.Login());`

But the Pages.Login() is of the wrong type with this exception:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi9H2.png)

Comment: please do not post errors or exceptions as images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you've provided, it seems that your class `Pages.Login` - while being in a `Pages` namespace - does not [inherit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/inheritance) from `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Page`, and therefore cannot be used in the place of a page.

Try making `Pages.Login` a child of [`Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Page`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.page?view=net-maui-7.0).
Here's an example:

```cs
namespace Pages;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

internal class Login : Page {
    // Class contents...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didnt manage to solve it direcly via the class, but I did this in the .razor page:

```
@page "/"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/login");
    }
}
```